# Moving Average / Rolling Average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics, subquery

I have 2 columns in MS SQL one is Serial no. and other is values. I need the thrird column which gives me the sum of the value in that row and the next 2.

Ex

```
SNo values
1 2
2 3
3 1
4 2
5 6
7 9
8 3
9 2
```

So I need third column which has sum of 2+3+1, 3+1+2 and So on, so the 8th and 9th row will not have any values:

```
1   2   6   
2   3   6   
3   1   4   
4   2   5   
5   1   6   
7   2   7   
8   3       
9   2
```

Can the Solution be generic so that I can Varry the current window size of adding 3 numbers to a bigger number say 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87dcd/82/0) that demonstrates the following query:

```
WITH TempS as 
(
  SELECT s.SNo, s.value, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.SNo) AS RowNumber
  FROM MyTable AS s
)
SELECT m.SNo, m.value,
(
  SELECT SUM(s.value) 
  FROM TempS AS s
  WHERE RowNumber >= m.RowNumber
  AND RowNumber <= m.RowNumber + 2
) AS Sum3InRow
FROM TempS AS m
```

In your question you were asking to sum 3 consecutive values.  You modified your question saying the number of consecutive records you need to sum could change.  In the above query you simple need to change the `m.RowNumber + 2` to what ever you need.

So if you need 60, then use

```
m.RowNumber + 59
```

As you can see it is very flexible since you only have to change one number.

Answer (score 1):

In case the `sno` field is not sequential, you can use `row_number()` with aggregation:

```
with ss as (
      select sno, values, row_number() over (order by sno) as seqnum
      from s
     )
select s1.sno, s1.values,
       (case when count(s2.values) = 3 then sum(s2.values) end) as avg3
from ss s1 left outer join
     ss s2
     on s2.seqnum between s1.seqnum - 2 and s1.seqnum
group by s1.sno, s1.values;
```

Comment: Hi gordon, This is the result I am getting from your query. (Posted above).
I added order by to it. It should leave the last 2 row as Null. can you Help? Also we have to change 3  and seqnum - 2 to the desired N and seqnum - (N-1) right?

Answer (score 0):

```
select one.sno, one.values, one.values+two.values+three.values as thesum
from yourtable as one
left join yourtable as two
on one.sno=two.sno-1
left join yourtable as three
on one.sno=three.sno-2
```

Or, as requested in your comment, you could do this:

```
select sno, sum(values)
over (
    order by sno
    rows between current row and 3 following
)
from yourtable
```

Comment: Is is Possible to make this generic as I have to vary the windows size of 3 to upto 60 and making so many joins will be very slow and resource consuming.

Comment: This query would not work with the sample data provided.  In the sample data `SNo` 6 is missing. So for `SNo` 5 it is added 5, 7, and 8  together.

Comment: Good catch, Linger. I just assumed...

The second query should work fine, though. Just need to modify the 3 to be the desired number.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a fully generic solution, where you can sum, for example, current row + next row + 5th following row:

Step 1: Create an table listing the offsets needed.  0 = current row, 1 = next row, -1 = prev row, etc

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (0),(1),(2)
) o(offset)
```

Step 2: Use that offset table in this template (via CTE or an actual table):

```
WITH o AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2) ) o(offset))
SELECT
  t1.sno,
  t1.value,
  SUM(t2.Value)
FROM @t t1
INNER JOIN @t t2 CROSS JOIN o
  ON t2.sno = t1.sno + o.offset
GROUP BY t1.sno,t1.value
ORDER BY t1.sno
```

Also, if SNo is not sequential, you can fetch ROW_NUMBER() and join on that instead.

```
WITH
  o AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2) ) o(offset)),
  t AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sno) i FROM @t)
SELECT
  t1.sno,
  t1.value,
  SUM(t2.Value)
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 CROSS JOIN o
  ON t2.i = t1.i + o.offset
GROUP BY t1.sno,t1.value
ORDER BY t1.sno
```